# Codeigniter - CI_Controller vs Controller

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to follow some tutorials regarding CodeIgniter, in particular ones about extending the controller, the tutorial I am following says that in the MY_Controller file I should put the following:

```
    <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

However when I do that I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /home/chimeri1/public_html/application/libraries/MY_Controller.php on line 3**

If however I put `CI_Cntroller` instead of `Controller` it works. What is the differance?

Also should the closing php tag `?>` be added to the bottom of the MY_Controller file, some tutorials miss this out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In any version before 2, `Controller` is the base controller class (which you would extend with MY_Controller). In version 2 and up, you need to extend `CI_Controller` as this is the new name for the base controller class.

For anyone else coming across this, CI2 moved several class files from the `/libraries` to the new `/core` directory. If you take a look in `system/core`, every class you see there is now using the `CI_` prefix - including Model (now CI_Model), Input, Loader, Lang, and many others. If you need to overload or extend these libraries, they now need to be in the `application/core` directory. You still will use the `MY_` prefix to extend them, or whatever you have set in your `$config['subclass_prefix']`.

With the release of version 2, CI split into two branches: Core and Reactor. Don't be confused - they are both CodeIgniter, but any reference to "Reactor" is the current community driven version which is offered as the main download on the website, while Core is the older EllisLabs version with less features. From the CI website:

> "Put simply, Reactor = CodeIgniter".

You can read more about the branch changes [here](http://codeigniter.com/news/codeigniter_2.0.0_released/).

Upgrading from 1.7.2 to 2.X is easy. As always, make sure to the read the [change log](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html) and [upgrade instructions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) when updating to a new version.

As far as the closing tag goes: it *is* optional, but you should avoid it when possible as it can introduce white space to the script (anything after the closing tag), which can mess up headers and appear in your output. As you know, the user guide recommends that you [do not use it](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php_closing_tag).

Comment: Thanks, that makes complete sense.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I searched all over before I found this. Time to update the "Getting Started" video because it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

In CodeIgniter 2.x, the Controller class has been renamed to `CI_Controller`. The tutorial you're using is most likely using CodeIgniter 1.7 or earlier, when `Controller` was the correct class to extend.

Regarding the closing `?>` tag, the [CodeIgniter style guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php_closing_tag) recommends **omitting** it, since accidental white space after that tag can be problematic.

Comment: Thank you too, you must have been seconds too late!

Comment: @James - if you look at the timestamp (hover over the time), mine was posted first. No worries, though.

Comment: FYI, not only is Controller now CI_Controller, but the models etc have changed in the same way e.g. CI_Model etc...