# CodeIgniter extending Controller not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I use `Class Hello extends CI_Controller` in the CodeIgniter framework, everything runs fine. But when I run `Class Hello extends Controller`, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in C......
>   on line 2

Anybody know whats going on? Is the Controller class in CodeIgniter deprecated or something of that nature?

Comment: Controllers must extend `CI_Controller`, that's the name of the controller's core class.

Comment: Hmm, so why in tutorials they reference Controller, and it works on their servers, but when I write the same code and run it on my server it crashes with Fatal Errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doesn't appear so, the latest doc link http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: it appears you have it reversed, Controller was prior to CodeIgniter v2.0 and now it's CI_Controller, here's a dupe post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613767/codeigniter-ci-controller-vs-controller)

Comment: Okay, so it's been replaced? That's what I figured. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you need to extend CI_Controller, like:

```
class Hello extends CI_Controller {
```

If it would have been in versions prior to 2.0.0, your

```
class Hello extends Controller {
```

would have worked.
Hope it helps