# CodeIgniter basic controller extends

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to extend basic controller by my own. This is code of file `MY_Secure.php` which i put in `application/libraries`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

Class MY_Secure extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    if(!$this->session->userdata('status') == 'admin') {
        $data['message'] = '<p class="error">You shold login in admin area</p>';
        $this->load->view('admin/login', $data);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

And here is my controller in `application/controllers/category.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Category extends MY_Secure {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

 public function index()
{
 $data['login'] = $this->session->userdata('login');
 $data['status'] = $this->session->userdata('status');

 $this->load->model('categories_model');
 $data['main_categories'] = $this->categories_model->get_main_categories();

 $this->load->view('admin/headers/main', $data);
 $this->load->view('admin/category');
 $this->load->view('admin/footer/main');
}
?>
```

But i have an error `Fatal error: Class 'MY_Secure' not found in Z:\home\ci.local\www\application\controllers\admin\category.php on line 3` How can i avoid this error? What i do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/182186/#862394

...so put <strike>MY_Secure.php</strike> MY_Controller.php in application/core

Comment: That`s meen that i could have only one controller, which can extends basic controllers?

Comment: at this stage I am satisfied by one controller, thanks. But what shoul`d i do, when i have a need to another one?

Comment: No, you can have as many controllers as you want. But *extending* the core controller is not the same thing as making *new* controllers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613767/codeigniter-ci-controller-vs-controller http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: i extnad contrler like this I extand URL of codeingniter with basic url structe: <? php
class save_user_contrller extends MY_COntroller {
function save_users() {
  $this -> usersModel -> save(MD5 ($this->input->post('login')));
}

Comment: Mr westley: extnad is not yet a valid codnighter variance. Not until the next release.

Comment: @mr westly extnad now available

Answer (score 1):

There is no required condition to save or name it is as `MY_Controller`. You can name it eg: `Mysite_Controller` if you'd like.

Please put your class in the `application/core` folder and then extend this class from your controller class.

But in order for that to work properly, you need to change config file value:

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'Mysite_'; // default  it is 'MY_'
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can not name your extends controller '`MY_Secure`', you must name it '`MY_Controller`'. Then extend it

```
class Category extends MY_Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the location of MY_Secure.php. The MY_ prefix works if you have not changed it in the config.

MY_Secure class must be saved in Applications Core folder for it to work in CodeIgniter 2.O not in Libraries folder.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Sturgeon has a really nice blog post on this:
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY