# What is CI_Controller built_in class? whether it is abstract or not?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have searched alot that what is CI_Controller class? Actually, it is a base class and all controllers extend from CI_Controller class in codeigniter? Whether, it is abstract class or not?

Comment: I hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613767/codeigniter-ci-controller-vs-controller

Comment: Actually, your link mostly debate on Controller and CI_Controller that is, before Codeigniter-2 , Controller was using and now CI_ prefix is used.

Comment: I wanted to know that whether it is an abstract class or not?

Answer (score 3):

in your directory structure open system->core->controller.php you will see the class name is CI_Controller

[image]

Comment: Thank you. CI_Controller is not an abstract class as there is no abstract keyword or any abstract method is used in that class.

Comment: exactly . and you can define a function in this class which you can use in any class which you extend from it